# Prove that for $R$ a ring with unity and $M_R$ an $R$-module, the set of elements in $M$ which annihilate $I^k$, $I$ an ideal, is a submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals

**Question**: Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ (a ring with unity). Let $M'$ be the subset of elements $a$ of $M$ that are annihilated by some power, $I^k$, of the ideal $I$, where the power may depend on $a$. Prove that $M'$ is a submodule of $M$.

**Proof**: Let $r \in R$ and $x, y \in M'$.

Note that $-y \in M'$ because $I^ly = \{0\}, l \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ and $\{0\} = I^l0 = I^l(y - y) = I^ly + -I^ly = \{0\} + -I^ly = -I^ly $ hence $-y \in M'$

$I^kx = \{0\}$ and $I^ly = \{0\}$ for $k, l \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$

If $k \geq l$ $\Rightarrow$ $I^k(-y) = I^{k-l}I^l(-y) = I^{k-l}\{0\} = \{0\}$

Also $Ir \subseteq I$ so then $I^krx \subseteq I^kx = \{0\}$. This allows us to have $I^k(rx + (-y)) = I^krx + I^k(-y)) = \{0\} + \{0\} = \{0\}$

If $l > k$ we have a very similar argument.

Thus $M'$ is a submodule of $M$.

This is an exercise from Dummit and Foote with a note that says to use a previous exercise where we prove that the infinite union of an ascending chain submodules is a submodule. I did not use that theorem and am unsure if I have missed something crucial in this proof or if there is simply an alternative way to use it.

Comment: Just another, less explicit, way to say the same. The modules would be the elements annihilated by each $I^k$. You can see in your argument the parts where you show that these are submodules, and the part "If $k\geq l\implies I^k...=I^{k-l}I^k...$" in which you prove that they are ascending.

Comment: Your proof is correct. As @OscarRascal said, it's implicitly the same as the hint.